# how to add leading and trailing to button in cell

Tags: ios, xcode, constraints, cell

I have trouble adding constraint to a cell if I set it right in iPhone 6,7 it will changes place in iPhone 5 size:and vice versa

[image: iPhone 5s] [image: iPhone 7] [image: this one]

Comment: give top,trailing,height and width constraints remove leading.

Comment: how to add it in code then nothing work i didn't get no trailing

Comment: what are you doing in code? it's to be done from storyboard only, firstly remove button constraints. Now select "Pin menu" at bottom right, then select top, trailing, height and width, and also uncheck constraints to margins.

Comment: there is no trailing man @Tushar Sharma

Comment: leading means left and trailing means right, so there will be 4 pins in "pin menu" , so kindly select button and go to pin menu, and click on top,right,height and width.How come it's not there check properly.

Comment: i got this error check this image i edit my question

Comment: i add what you ask top,right,buttom, i have tried everything it's maybe xcode error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159631/discussion-between-tushar-sharma-and-mazenqp).

Answer (score 1):

It *doesn't* change place relative to the *left* side, which is what you are pinning it to. It's doing exactly what you told it to do.

If what you wanted was that it should stay the same distance from the *right* side, you should pin it to *right* side, not the left.

Comment: this is just pic explaining what I'm trying to do remove the -1 you but it understand the question first then ask me what i want if you don't get it then if i was that stupid you can mark me @matt

Answer (score 0):

- You need to give right constraint for button to right edge of cell
- Left constraint of button to full name label
- Remove constraint to left edge of cell from button

Hope this will solve your problem :)